# ndb.PolyModel as an ancestor of a regular entity -- bad idea?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to make a ndb.PolyModel child entity an ancestor of another ndb.Model entity, because I need the child entity to be strongly consistent for queries.

Something about this makes me nervous. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the secret sauce behind a ndb.PolyModel is that instances of it have a special property called 'class'.

This is a repeated property of strings of all the class names in the inheritance chain, which ndb then uses to instantiate the appropriate subclass when it pulls it out of datastore.

The key for each instance will still be of the parent class.

So for the following example:

```
class Animal(ndb.PolyModel):

class Cat(Animal):

class Dog(Animal):
```

If you do

```
d = Dog(...)
d.put()
```

`d.key` will still be something like `ndb.Key('Animal', 123456789)`

In your Datastore Viewer, you will only have an `Animal` table and not a `Dog` table nor a `Cat` table.

So I would imagine you should be safe to use `ndb.Key('Animal', 123456789)` as the ancestor for some other model.